# Post erroneously rejected because "it appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code"

Tags: support, asking-questions, code-formatting

What exactly is wrong with the following text that generates the error:

The complete web page and script can be found:
[HERE]
(http://www3.telus.net/public/horsma01/index.shtml)
[or HERE]
(http://macrodm.atwebpages.com/release/RelsNext/MdmWebPages/MdmMain.shtml)
but stay on the home page the rest isn't updated.

It comes from a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653474/does-object-literal-notation-execute-faster).

If you have the above problem, (in future) it saves a lot of time to just **systematically turn blocks of text to code until find the offending text**.  I wasted huge time by not considering the links as a potential problem.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess it's actually the HTML you used instead of markdown  (for the lists) that might be causing your problem. Just use proper markdown and I don't think you'll have the same issue with the links.

Answer (score 1):

You had all that block indented 4 spaces - that indicates to markdown that it is a code block, to be rendered as is.

I have removed the indentation and all is well now.

Comment: He made it a code-block to get rid of the "not properly formatted as code" warning. That was his real problem. The wrong formatting was only a result of that I think. Unless I didn't get the point. I'd say the real issue is the HTML he used before it.

Comment: @Bart - possibly. Question is on-hold now, so kinda moot.

Comment: I am mystified.  The link lines were never indented originally and were merely changed to code (indented) as a fix.  Thanks for the help, I am going to try to recreate the problem now.  

@Bart, I'm quite surprised the HTML was happily accepted but it was only used in a frustration before I realized the problem was the link lines.  I like the HTML option.

Comment: I have edited the above question to now include the original text that caused the problem.  I of course cannot leave that format in my object literal question but am now playing around to see what exactly it doesn't like.

Comment: @Oded and Bart.  OK I got it finally.  Somehow, a line break got introduced after the ] as in [text](link) had a line break between ] and (.

I thought it was word wrapping but just realized that couldn't be true.

Thanks for you help on this.  Oded's fix looked different from my original and led to the solution.